# Business Central or Drools Workbench authentication error (proxy error)

Tags: maven, drools, jbpm

I am trying to work with Business Central/Drools Workbench. I am using the tutorial as described in [Here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/getting-started-with-business-central-workbench). While, building the project, I have the following error :

```
maven pom.xml found, but unable to read org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model [FATAL] Non-readable POM : input contained no data @ for project
```

and

```
NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
```

I understand that this points to the authentication problem.
I have done the following:
Added the proxy settings to my `settings.xml` (The proxy works within the eclipse maven env). added the following line in my `standalone.xml` as described in [2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.0/html/packaging_and_deploying_a_decision_service/maven-deployment)

```
<property name="kie.maven.settings.custom" value="file:///Users/abcd/.m2/Settings.xml"/>
```

I have also tried it without the `file:///`

Comment: Is your kie-server and business-central deployed on the same application server / JVM ?

Comment: Yes [link](https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/o9P8Xe8Ffi)